# Connecting to a *specific* remote folder with Files application (over `sftp`), instead of default user home directory

Tags: files, filemanager, sftp

Using the Ubuntu normal "Files" application you can click "Other Locations" and then connect to a remote server over `sftp` like this:

```
sftp://user@123.123.123.123
```

But what if I want to start in `/var/www/website.com/public_html` instead of the `user` home folder?

I tried these:

```
sftp://user@123.123.123.123/var/www/website.com/public_html
sftp://user@123.123.123.123/../var/www/website.com/public_html
```

but they take me to the `user` home folder still.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to connect with `sftp://user@123.123.123.123` and then navigate to the folder that I want to start at, and then right click inside the folder and click "Add bookmark". Now I've got a bookmark that I can click which takes me straight to the folder I wanted.